# Unit testing asynchronous HTTP request function

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, asynchronous

I'm trying to write unit tests in XCode, but i encountered problem with asynchronous function. The main idea is to check the length of received JSON

The function I'm trying to test (existing in someVC class):

```swift
func getSomeCount(url: String){
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                self.someJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                self.length = self.someJSON!.count
            }else{
                self.length = 0
                print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            }
        }
    }
```

and the test looks like this:

```
func testAPIResponse(){
        let someVC = SomeVC()
        someVC.getSomeCount(url: "http:\\www.someapi.com")
        XCTAssertEqual(someVC.length, 1234)
}
```

I know that I should use expectations, but don't know how to implement them correctly in this case. The tests fails saying that 0 is not equal to 1234. How it should be done properly?

Comment: You (a) need to give your method an `@escaping` completion handler and the (b) use `XCTestExpectation` and fulfill the expectation in the completion handler. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/testing_asynchronous_operations_with_expectations.

Comment: As an aside, when writing unit tests for network API, we sometimes “mock” the server responses so that our unit tests are independent of external servers, networks, etc. See https://jeroenscode.com/mocking-alamofire/.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, looks like I need to dig a little bit more into this.